Amcharts 4: Series clustering by month
I have a series of a value and a date.
The date could span multiple years, but the value will reflect the monthly value.
i.e.
[
  ...,
  {
    value: 10,
    date: "Jun 22"
  },
  {
    value: 11, 
    date: "Jul 22" 
  },
  ...,
  {
    value: 14,
    date: "Jun 23"
  },
  {
    value: 13,
    date: "Jul 23",
  },
  ...,
]

What I'm looking to achieve is if there is a way to cluster these values by their month,
So that i'd have a chart that shows an axis from Jan to Dec, while each month would have a bar for each year to compare the same month of different years.
Can this be achieved in one data object? Do i have to split this and process the data into separate categories.
